# Mapping dictionary with list of same keys to get values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary id_names of the form:

```
1: 'Nightwatch (1997)', 
2: 'Nobody Loves Me (Keiner liebt mich) (1994)', 
3: 'Wife, The 
.
.
.
100: 'Lamerica (1994)'
```

Where they key represents movie id and value the movie name.

I am iterating through a list high :

```
# Finding 5 highest values 
high = k.most_common(5) 

for i in high: 
   print(i[0]," :",i[1]," ")
```

with outpout:

```
3 : 5.5  
16  : 4.4
7  : 3.7  
42 : 3.6 
83  : 3.3
```

The keys of this list are the same keys of the dictionary id_movies. What I want is to somehow map the two, so that i can get the name of the movie as well as the score.

I am trying something like this :

```
for i in high: 

print(i[0]," :",i[1]," ") 
for name, age in id_names.iteritems():
   print(movie_titles1[i[0]])
```

but i know this isn't how python dictionaries are supposed to work...

Comment: search for `python list comprehension` tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case the value of `i[0]` is your dictionary-key: you could get the corresponding name from the movies-dictionary using this key:

```
for i in high: 
    print(i[0], ":", i[1], movies.get(i[0]))
```

in case you want to store the title and release date of the movies as separate values in your dict, you could import from collections a defaultdict() and using a list as the value having separate entries for the date and title.

```
from collections import defaultdict


movies = defaultdict(list)
movies['1'] = ['Nightwatch', '1997']
movies['2'] = ['Nobody Loves Me (Keiner liebt mich)', '1994']
movies['3'] = ['Wife, The', None]


high = [['3',5.5],['2',4.2],['1',3.7]]

for i in high:
    print(i[0], ":", i[1], "; Title: ", movies.get(i[0])[0],';', "release date: ", movies.get(i[0])[1])
```

Output:

```
3 : 5.5 ; Title:  Wife, The ; release date:  None
2 : 4.2 ; Title:  Nobody Loves Me (Keiner liebt mich) ; release date:  1994
1 : 3.7 ; Title:  Nightwatch ; release date:  1997
```

Comment: I have tried that already, it doesn't work. It returns a value of None

Comment: Could you share more of your script, so we could see, where exactly it is breaking?

Comment: I think the problem might be on my movie titles dictionary. I turned it into a dictionary from a 2 column dataframe containing the id and movie title. I used the method .to_dict to do that. I belive the dictionary isn't in the right form

Comment: yes your response was actaully correct, i will accept your answer, thank you fro your interest

Comment: just checking the to_dict() method in the pandas module: 
There is an option to use defaultdicts aswell, in you have split the data.
[to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Haven't been using pandas in a while. In case you want to have accessible rows of the data frame in your dict, we could look over it tomorrow.